# What's the official location for documentation on the Cucumber command line arguments?

Tags: cucumber

I'd like to run Cucumber from the command line and Maven through cuke4duke. Where can I find the complete list of command line arguments? I'm particularly interested in the debugging options.

Most of the documentation I've found are for worked examples (which is good), but I can't find anything similar to a man page.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best source of information is the built-in help!

```
cucumber -h
```

There are also a few extra examples and information on running Cucumber through Rake etc on the [Running Features](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Running-Features) page on the Cucumber wiki.